# How does subtracting an exponent from an exponent return a greater value?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm just stuck on a problem where I have to simplify an expression. This is the expression:

$\sqrt{x^2\:-\:\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2}$

The textbook has the answer as:

$\frac{\sqrt{3}x}{2}$

I have no idea how to get to that. I've tried to figure it out for the past hour and I have tried online solvers but I can't understand what the steps are. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $x^2-\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2=\dfrac{3x^2}4$

Comment: A little bit picky, but the text-book is wrong.  The expression actually simplifies to $\frac  {|x|\sqrt3}{2}$

Comment: @DougM Not picky at all, I would say.

Comment: J.W. I understand that but where do you get the 3 from?

Comment: $x^2-\left(\dfrac x2\right)^2=\dfrac{4x^2}4-\dfrac{x^2}4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step a time!

You solution assumes that $x\ge 0$.

\begin{align}
x^2-(\frac{x}{2})^2
&=x^2-\frac{x^2}{4}\\
&=1\cdot x^2-\frac{1}{4}\cdot x^2\\
&=(1-\frac{1}{4})x^2=
\frac34 x^2
\end{align}

So
$$
\sqrt{x^2-(\frac{x}{2})^2}=\sqrt{\frac34 x^2}
=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{4}}\sqrt{x^2}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}x\quad x\ge 0
$$